# Recent Eclipse Oxygen Version does not support CVS plugin

Tags: eclipse

Recent Eclipse Oxygen Version does not support CVS plugin. Any thoughts on how to configure CVS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CVS code is no longer included in the core Eclipse distributions.

It is still available in 'Help > Install New Software...' and select the main update site for your release in the 'Work with' combo. Search for 'CVS'

Comment: I could not find Select Main Update in Install New software. Please let me know where it will be

Comment: I mean you choose the update site that corresponds to your release in the 'Work with' drop down - probably something like `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/4.7` for Oxygen

Comment: Ya got it. I really appreciate your help.